# Should a submit button be disabled by default for an inline form with only one input field?

Tags: forms, submit

For example:

YouTube disables the comment button by default, and only enables it once text has been entered:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

The general consensus on ux.stackexchange.com is to not disable submit buttons and wait to present errors until after the user has hit the submit button.

- [Form validation and disabled buttons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76301/form-validation-and-disabled-buttons)
- [Disabled submit button on form vs allow submit then show errors?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/disabled-submit-button-on-form-vs-allow-submit-then-show-errors)
- [Disabling submit-button until the user has completed the form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17905/disabling-submit-button-until-the-user-has-completed-the-form)

Would this mean that YouTube is going against best UX practices?
Or is this justifiable behavior?

Comment: The only valid answer is "we don't know" unless the designer of YouTube decides to answer.

Comment: UX is not the only consideration too (and sometimes is just dealers choice really). I’ve had projects where buttons are replaced once validated action is registered to stave off bots and the like. If that’s the case then form follows factor. A million forms on a million nodes... might be part of it, haven’t looked though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pragmatically this isn't a form that needs to be validated.

Technically, yes, but it's just one field and 1 simple issue: is there text entered? There's no check for date formatting, if an email works, if a password is safe enough or anything commonly done with a form. So there's not the same cognitive load.

As the other thread mentions, users have two modes; completion mode (just filling everything) and correction mode. A youtube comment doesn't require any correction, so if it's done, you can just submit it.

In fact, one could argue that this is better for the user experience, because once you start typing, the button changes, thus highlighting the next course of action.

Comment: "A youtube comment doesn't require any correction". Doesn't it have a maximum number of characters it can have, for example?